# List instance of monad in Haskell - why use concat in bind-operation?

Tags: list, function, haskell, monads

I found some question here: [Redefining monad list instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276389/redefining-monad-list-instance). I'm currently trying to get my head wrapped around monads. But I need some help here, I don't get the instance-definition of lists as monads.

This is my given definition of a list-instance for a monad:

```
    instance Monad [] where
    xs >>= f = concat $ map f xs
    return x = [x]
    fail _ = []
```

I dont understand, why I need concat in the bind-function.
This is my definition of `(>>=)`:

```
    (>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So I have some monadic value `m a` and a function, taking a value `a` and producing a monadic value `m b` given as parameters. I 'feed' `a` from `m a` into the function `(a -> m b)` and thus get a monadic value `m b` as a result.
In my own words: The bind-operator `(>>=)` allows to chain monadic functions (returning monadic values) where the value of the output of the earlier function is the input for the next function. Right?

Back to the list-instance. `map f xs` uses the function `f` on every value in `xs`. So `map (*2) [1,2,3]` results in `[2,4,6]`. And that's all I wanted here or not? How should I use `concat` here?
The definition of `concat` is as follows:

```
    concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

Why do I get a list of lists in the `(>>=)`-function? Is it because list is the monad and I take every single value from that list to feed it to `f` and `map` just gets singleton-inputs? But how do I iterate over the whole list then? Where does the 'picking each value' happen? And if `map` takes the whole list xs as input (that's how I understand it) why should I get a list of lists?

Comment: Becaue the type of `>>=` is `(a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`. So the `f` we use with `map` will produce a list of lists of `b`s, so we need to convert that to a `[b]` again.

Comment: Ah! If it was `(a -> m b) -> m a -> b` I would not need concat. But because of that `m b` where `m` is the list I get a list of singleton-lists?

Comment: The type signature in your comment is a bit of a weird one. Do you mean `(a -> b) -> m a -> m b`? That seems to match more with your conclusion that you wouldn't need concat. And in fact that is a very useful function: it is `fmap`, from `Functor`.

Comment: Note that in category theory, monads are defined using `return :: a -> m a` and `join :: m (m a) -> m a`. `concat` is effectively filling the purpose of `join`, which can be used to implement `xs >>= f = join (fmap f xs)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If

```
x :: [a]
f :: a -> [b]
```

then

```
map f :: [a] -> [[b]]
map f x :: [[b]]
```

so, we need to flatten the latter into `[b]`. This is done by `concat`.

Note how `f` was already producing a list, so `map` makes that into a list-of-lists. This is crucial: if `f` was not producing a list but were `f :: a->b`, then we don't need `concat` -- we don't even need a monad, since a functor providing `fmap=map :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]` would be enough.

The added benefit of a monad over a functor mainly lies in letting `f` produce a value in a monadic type.